# File permissions to lampp in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin

I gave wrong permissions to the lampp folder (777)

It gave me the error as follows:

> phpMyAdmin - Error Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not
>   be world writable!

The image can be previewed here: http://postimg.org/image/8imdihtyr/full/

Later, I changed the file permissions to (755). The screenshot being: http://postimg.org/image/gui4jqrcj/full/ . I now receive the error:

> "No file or directory"

I'm able to access the localhost, and the folders inside it, but not phpmyadmin.

How can I make my phpmyadmin available to myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to Super User

```
sudo su
```

Then give permission as 755

```
chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp/lampp
```

Then Stop and Start your Lampp

```
/opt/lampp/lampp stop
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Now open your localhost, localhost/phpmyadmin and the localhost/subfolders

Reply if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I had in my case done the following

`sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp`

and encoutered the php admin issue but was able to fix it with just

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp
```